# web service can be browse from remote iis but not on internet

Tags: web-services, iis, web-applications, webserver, asmx

There is a web service that currently is published and can be browsed on internet.
I have copied the service folder located in wwwroot and I paste it in the same location changing the name.

Both were hosted on the Default site.

From IIS Manager I have converted the copied folder as application, if a browse it locally, works, if a browse it remotely within the same domain, works

[service works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ep6s.jpg)

But if I try doing it from internet can not be access and I receive the message

[service doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e35ay.png)

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

I've checked the Virtual Path and I have created another application pool, but it have not worked yet.

if somebody could suggest me something. Thanks

Regards.

J Fuentes.

Comment: "if I try doing it using the domain direction can not be access", what's that? I can hardly understand what you referred to, so a few screen shots might help.

Comment: Hi Alex maybe I'm not using the propers terms. I mean if I try browsing the web from internet doesn't work https:/nxv.bxxxxn.ax.xx/application/webservice.asmx but if i check in a computer within network vm-computername/application/webservice.asmx it works fine.

Comment: First, disable that page as no one should see it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187978/asp-net-web-service-any-way-to-disable-the-test-invoke-section Second, test whether your web service calls work, not the test page.