# How to configure ASP.NET Web Service to not Append Port Number to Request URL

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, asmx

I have a website in IIS that also has a sub-directory containing an ASP.NET webservice. The Website has a DNS entry of [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and the webservice is accessed via [www.mysite.com/service.asmx](http://www.mysite.com/service.asmx). I've deployed multiple instances of the site and service on different ports and setup the DNS entries so that the different sites can be accessed like [www.dev-mysite.com](http://www.dev-mysite.com) or [www.qa-mysite.com](http://www.qa-mysite.com).

The web service contains an 'Invoke' button on it's landing page that is used to submit a SOAP request. When I use the invoke button to submit the soap request using the site's IP like [www.172.168.0.1:9025/service.asmx](http://www.172.168.0.1:9025/service.asmx) everything is fine, but when I use the DNS URL the web service appends the port, so I get [www.dev-mysite.com:9025/service.asmx](http://www.dev-mysite.com:9025/service.asmx). This cause my request to fail as the end point is incorrect and should be: [www.dev-mysite.com/service.asmx](http://www.dev-mysite.com/service.asmx).

Do I need to use a WSDL file to resolve this problem or is this a configuration in IIS that I am missing?

Comment: However, you should disable that test page in a real world web app, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187978/asp-net-web-service-any-way-to-disable-the-test-invoke-section

Comment: You probably need to set port forwarding from port 9025 to port 80. May be also it's the website Binding settings in IIS.

Comment: I solved this some time ago by installing ARR and adding some inbound proxy rules to my main app web.config. ARR is free, and contains the port forwarding you'll need. https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

Comment: On my sides, the service invocation works properly.  Generally the issue only occurred when the IIS works as a reverse proxy, the service URL will display the proxy address instead of the actual service address. 
In the case of actual invocation to the service, we could change the service URL address by modifying the service configuration file. In other words, it doesn’t matter.